# sqlsrv driver not load in phpinfo() file in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, sqlsrv

I have windows server 2008 r2 32 bit.in server PHP 5.6 version. sqlsrv32.exe installed and extract ext folder in php and give extension in php.ini file.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

phpInfo() file  sqlsrv driver is not found. I have run sql server connection php file give error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()`

Comment: You don't want to load the `ts` versions of the extensions. Please comment them out, restart IIS and see what phpinfo() tells you.

Comment: sqlsrv is not load

Comment: Look in your extensions directory and see which sqlsrv extensions you have. You may have `pdo_php_sqlsrv_nts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_nts.dll` (without the `_56`).

Answer (score 0):

I usually follow these steps:

**Configuration of PHP** (I think that you have already done this):

Run this `<?echo phpinfo()?>;`

Check which confifuration file is loaded from "Loaded Configuration File" section.

Set your PHP environment:

- extension_dir="path_to_your_php_instalation\ext"
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

**Configuration of PHP Driver for SQL Server** (this may be your problem):

I think that you have downloaded sqlsrv32.exe. Versions 3.2 and 3.1 of the driver require Microsoft ODBC Driver 11. So, check IIS log file for any errors.

You can download the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434).

Answer (score 0):

I have meet my answer. ext folder of php given path in php.ini. My Problem is solved. Phpinfo() load the sqlsrv driver.